# Calling UI thread method from AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, methods, android-asynctask

I have a problem with calling the setadapter() method from the inside of AsyncTaskActivity onPostExecute() method. I've read docs about AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result) but found no answer how to achieve that. Should I use an Intent to do so? I'm new to a Android development so please forgive me if it's a kind of stupid question.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private String[] columns = new String[] {"foreign_word", "native_word"};
private int[] target = new int[] { R.id.foreign_word, R.id.native_word };
private Cursor cur = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     new AsyncTaskActivity(this).execute();
 }

    public void setadapter(Cursor cur)  {
        SimpleCursorAdapter aaa = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_entry, cur, columns, target, 0);
        this.setListAdapter(aaa);
    }
}
```

AsyncTaskActivity

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

Activity activity = null;
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private String[] selection = {"_id", "native_word", "foreign_word"};
Cursor cur = null;


public AsyncTaskActivity(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
    DbAdapter mSQLadapter = new DbAdapter(activity);
    db = mSQLadapter.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.query("words", selection, "foreign_word='car'", null, null, null, null);
    return cur;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cur) {

// I'd like to call setadapter() ,passing it Cursor as a parameter

   }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your AsyncTask is always called by `MainActivity`, do this

```
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cur) {
   MainActivity mActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
   mActivity.setadapter();
   }
```

You can specify more parameters for your `setAdapter` method so you can pass off the `Cursor`, `String` Array, etc.

However an even better method if the `AsyncTask` is only called from `MainActivity` is to make this `AsyncTask` a private inner class inside `MainActivity`. This will allow it to access all the global variables and methods of `MainActivity`

Comment: AsyncTask as a inner class inside the MainActivity works for me, but above code not (my setadapter() method was inaccessible).

Comment: @soulreaver It may have been because I forgot to declare mActivity as a reference of MainActivity. If you did just `Activity` mActivity it wouldn't have seen the method because `Activity` doesn't have a `setAdapter()` method whereas `MainActivity` does.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a little unusual, but to answer the question asked:

Change `activity` to a ListActivity:

```
ListActivity activity = null;
```

And use:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cur) {
    activity.setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(activity, R.layout.list_entry, cur, columns, target, 0));
}
```

---

You should look into using the LoaderManager class, it creates and handles background threads for you. You should also consider using a ContentProvider, it handles a lot of busy work for you as well.

Lastly AsyncTaskActivity is not an Activity, so this class name is a little confusing...

Comment: I know about the LoaderManager and Content Providers, but they seem to be too complicated for a beginner (which I am), and besides this solution seems to be code overhelming for simple apps.